# Can I transfer SDL_Textures from one SDL_Renderer to another?

Tags: c++, textures, sdl-2

Is it possible to render textures binded to a SDL_Renderer to another SDL_Renderer ? For example :

```
SDL_Renderer* render1, render2;
//initialization of renderers
SDL_Texture* texture = /* ... */; //created from render1
SDL_RenderCopy(render1, texture, NULL, NULL);
//ChangeRenderer(texture, render2) or something like that
SDL_RenderCopy(render2, teture, NULL, NULL);
```

Why I want to do this ? Because I have a `TextureManager` linked to my main `SDL_Renderer` (created from the window), but I want to use internally in a function another `SDL_Renderer` (from `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(SDL_Surface*)`) in order to return a texture instead of drawing directly on the main renderer.

So, is it possible ? Thank you for reading !

Comment: I'd say no, and for good reasons. You can use `SDL_Surface` though, and convert to texture on target renderer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is indeed impossible, but for my case I finally find the function `SDL_SetRenderTarget` which permits to render directly on a texture linked to my main renderer, so I do not need to use `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer`, nor `SDL_Surface`.